# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1. It was working before then I got this

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error

It seems to point at loadDogs(); and items[1], but I don't see any problem. It was working before with the same code, then I started to have these errors. I backed this code up before, but when I used the backup one; the result is still there. I tried to fix for an hour, but it didn't go away. It compiles although running it throws the error in eclipse.

```
    public class DogCompetitionManager     {
    private final String DOGS_FILE = "res/dogs.txt";
    private final String COURSE_FILE = "res/courses.txt";

    private ArrayList<Dogs>     dogsList;
    private ArrayList<Courses>  courseList;

    public DogCompetitionManager()
    {
        loadDogs();
        loadCourses();
        runAdministration();
    }

    private void loadDogs()
    {   // creates a dogsList array
        dogsList = new ArrayList<Dogs>();
        BufferedReader inFile = null;

        try
        {
            inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DOGS_FILE));
            String line = inFile.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                String[] items;
                items = line.split(" ");

                dogsList.add(new Dogs(items[0],
                            items[1],
                            Double.parseDouble(items[2]),
                            Integer.parseInt(items[3]),
                            items[4]));
                line = inFile.readLine();
            }
            inFile.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: Why don't you add a `catch` for `ArrayIndexOfOutBounds` and print `line` to see why it is throwing the exception

Comment: Check your `DOG_FILES` maybe you do not have 5 items on each row.

Comment: Did you debug your code? When did you get the exception? Perhaps it's the last line of your dogs-file?

Comment: 1) check the file, it should contains symbol you splitiing with; 2) guess is better use ";" as split item (like in *.csv)

Comment: Check your dog file. It has probably been modified and one of the lines does not adhere to the format you expect.

Comment: I went back to my DOG_FILE and deleted the last line that I added, and it worked! Thank you so much! I was thinking maybe of the extra next line that was giving me an exception error.

Answer (score 2):

Never trust user input!

```
String[] items;
items = line.split(" ");

dogsList.add(new Dogs(items[0],
                        items[1],
                        Double.parseDouble(items[2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(items[3]),
                        items[4]));
```

Here you split an input line and expect it to have a certain format. That is pretty unstable. You should first make sure, the line actually *has* that format and handle it accordingly if it has not.

At least you should do some output about the error. Then you could either just ignore the line and process the rest of the file or you could throw an exception, aborting the process. Depends on your requirements.

An easy check would be to look if the `String[]` has as many items as you expect after the split (or is null perhaps).

Example:

```
if( null == items || items.length < 5 ) { 
    // 1. LOG ERROR

    // To ignore line and move on:
    line = inFile.readLine();
    continue;
}
```

A more sophisticated one would be to use some kind of RegEx to see if there are numbers, where you expect them etc. I also suggest catching Parse-Errors, when converting strings to numeric values.